# correct use of "the other way round"

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, questions, writing

I was wondering if the use of "the other way round" in this sentence is correct.

Overall the sentence makes sense to me, but as a non-native speaker, I am wondering if it is idiomatic and comprehensible.

If not, could you kindly suggest an alternative solution?

Here's the sentence:

> If this analysis suggests that churches might take up the legal form of commercial businesses - and act as religious investors groups - this paper looks at the matter the other way round; that is, whether or not for-profit corporations themselves might operate as church-groups.

Comment: Some would say "around" rather than "round", but it's reasonably idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you @Lawrence I have just added more information to the question

Comment: @HotLicks A pond issue. In the UK it is "the other way round" (US - around). From the OP's name I suspect he may be Italian. EU schools tend to teach UK English.

Answer (score 0):

As written it's incorrect.  It should be, "the other way 'round" or "the other way around", meaning, "from the opposite point of view".  Fix that tiny flaw and it's correct, comprehensible and idiomatic.